# Travis-ci Host shut down during build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, travis-ci

We get frequent Travis failures with messages like this in the log, in the middle of what was up until then a smoothly-running cucumber test:

```
Broadcast message from root@testing-gce-88e5d0c1-136b-4871-ace1-0fdb36344b13
(unknown) at 23:25 ...
The system is going down for halt NOW!
Power button pressed
F-----------------------F----F---F-------F----------------
(::) failed steps (::)
Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away: ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_3 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

Splitting out the tests seems to reduce the chance of hitting it, but we need a proper solution. I found https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4924 which seems to be a similar issue, but that one says it shouldn't happen any more, and we're still seeing it most days.

We're running ruby on rails with tests in cucumber for features and rspec for unit tests, and our Travis.yml is set up to use the old-style travis with `sudo: required`. It's at https://github.com/otwcode/otwarchive/blob/master/.travis.yml.

How can we avoid or resolve this?

Comment: Is the tests suite taking too much time?

Answer (score 0):

Try another CI system. This should give you more information on the problem. There are lots of CI services where you can get a short trial period that should be sufficient to diagnose your problem. CircleCI (https://circleci.com) is a good one to try, as it seems to be quite smart about setup, and has good github integration.